# Выпадающее меню CSS

Tags: меню, css

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать  выпадающее меню. Вот что у меня получается: [ссылка на меню](http://jsfiddle.net/o7kauh39/).

```
.mim{
  display:none;
}
```

При наведении на пункт меню выпадал список, то есть:

```
.mim {display:block;}
```

Не могу понять, как сделать средствами css такое. )

Более наглядно скрины:

обычный режим:

[image]

и при `:hover` (наведении):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать такой селектор:

```
.nav_in:hover .mim {
    display: block;   
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/o7kauh39/2/)

А вообще я бы не рекомендовал делать меню по `hover`, в него бывает очень трудно попасть :)

**UPD.** Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/XGzmh/